# Group algebra $F[G]$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

While studying I came across the concept **group algebra** which is defined as
$$F[G]=\{\sum_{g \in G} \alpha_{g}g : \alpha_{g} \in F \text{ and } g \in G\}.$$

Can anybody tell what are the elements of this ring?

For example $a$ is an element so it is equal to $a= \alpha_{g_{1}}g_{1}+\alpha_{g_{2}}g_{2}.....+\alpha_{g_{n}}g_{n}$,
what is $\alpha_{g_{1}}$? why is the script $g$ used?

and if you can help me with this question:

$V$ is irreducible $C[G]$ module and $a$ is an element of the center of $C[G]$, $a \in Z(C[G])$. I wanna show that for every element of $V$ there exists element $\gamma \in C$ s.t. $v a = \gamma v$ and $C$ is the set of complex numbers.

Here is my attempt:

I define the map $\theta:V\rightarrow V$ which takes the element $v\in V$ to its image $va\in V$.
$\theta$ is an endomorphism  and its inverse is also an endomorphism ($V$ is irreducible.)

so I try to make use of that. Do you think my appraoch is right?

I'm sorry for the bad writing but it is the first time to write using the notations.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $F[G]$ is not a group. It is a ring, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring).

Comment: do you know what deos the summation mean? is the summation over elements of G or elemnets of F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to take only formal (finite) sums of formal products. An example can be useful to grasp the concept: Lets take the ring $\mathbb Z_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and the group $S_3 = \{e,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}$. Then the elements of $R[G] = \mathbb Z_4[S_3]$ are things like $u = 3x+2xy$ or $v = 2x+3x^2y$. How do you add them? like this $u+v = (3+2)x+2xy+3x^2y = x+2xy+3x^2y$ (since $3+2=1$ in $\mathbb Z_4$). How do you multiply them? Distribute, multiplying the coefficients with the product of $\mathbb Z_4$ and the group elements with the group operation: $u v = (3x+2xy)(2x+3x^2y) = 3\cdot 2 x^2+3\cdot 3 x^3y + 2\cdot 2xyx+2\cdot 3xyx^2y = 2x^2+y+2x^2$  (since in $\mathbb Z_4$ we have $3\cdot2 = 2$, $3\cdot3=1$, $2\cdot 2 = 0$ and $2\cdot 3=2$ and in $S_3$ we have $x^3y = y$ and $xyx^2y = x^2$) which simplifies even more because $2x^2+2x^2 = 0$, so $u v= y$.

In a more general setup you represent each element as a sum of elements of $G$ with coefficients of $R$: $$u = \sum_{g\in G}r_g g$$ If $G$ is infinite you restrict to the formal sums that have only a finite number of coefficients not $0$.

You add them and multiply them as in the example.

Comment: so can I consider the element $\sum_{g\in G} 1g$ the identity element for the multiplication ?

Comment: No, look at the example: $\sum_{g\in G} 1g$ would be $e+x+x^2+y+xy+x^2y$. If you multiply $2e$ (for example) with that you would get $2e+2x+2x^2+2y+2xy+2x^2y$, not $2e$.

Comment: but would it be in the center of the ring? I tried multiply it with *u* but it did not seem to me commutitave

Comment: is $G\in R[G]$?

Comment: Did you meant to ask "is $G \subset R[G]$"?

Comment: yes I used the wrong notation